# python different result in function call but the same code. Python Bug

Tags: python

As you can see, to generate these two graphs, I run same piece of code but one calling the function which contains the code another not. Because theses graphs are results on the statistic distribution, so I expect results share the same distribution when I iterate 5000 same processes. But it turns out not. I am stuck at this problem now.

Running Environment

default python 3.7 environments installed by anaconda

Mac 10.15 Catalina

[jupyternotebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UrbX.png)

This is the raw code you can reproduce it by typing

```
import numpy as np
import math
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
def data_generation(sample_size,w):
    g_x = np.random.randn(sample_size,10)
    g_w.reshape(10,1)
    g_y_prob = [sigmoid(x) for x in np.matmul(g_x,g_w)];
    g_y = [np.random.random()<x for x in g_y_prob]
    for i in range(sample_size):
        prob = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-w.dot(g_x[i])))
        g_y[i] = np.random.choice([0.0, 1.0], p=[1-g_y_prob[i], g_y_prob[i]])
    return g_x,g_y
def wrapped_logreg(x,y,iter_num):
    clf = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear',max_iter=iter_num)
    result = clf.fit(g_x,g_y)
    return result.coef_

def running_plotting():
    np.random.seed(1)
    norm_average_log = [];
    for i in range(5000):
        g_w = np.random.randn(10);
        g_w = g_w/np.linalg.norm(g_w)
        g_x,g_y = data_generation(50,g_w)
        t_w_log = wrapped_logreg(g_x,g_y,100000)
        norm_average_log.append(np.linalg.norm(g_w - t_w_log))
    return norm_average_log
norm_hist_1 = []
np.random.seed(1)
for i in range(5000):
    g_w = np.random.randn(10);
    g_w = g_w/np.linalg.norm(g_w)
    g_x,g_y = data_generation(50,g_w)
    t_w_log = wrapped_logreg(g_x,g_y,100000)
    norm_hist_1.append(np.linalg.norm(g_w - t_w_log))
np.random.seed(1)
norm_hist_2 = running_plotting()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.hist(norm_hist_1)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.hist(norm_hist_2)
```